# How to chain context managers in python?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Long story short, what would be the right way to get second snippet of code to work exactly like the first one?

```
stack_device = [None]
stack_context = [None]

@contextlib.contextmanager
def device(device):
    stack_device.append(device)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        stack_device.pop()


@contextlib.contextmanager
def context(ctx):
    stack_context.append(ctx)
    try:
        with device("dev"):
            yield
    finally:
        stack_context.pop()


with context("myctx"):
    print(stack_device[-1])  # -> dev
    print(stack_context[-1]) # -> ctx
```

And that one, of course, would not have the right device set when I need it:

```
stack_device = [None]
stack_context = [None]

class Device():
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def __enter__(self):
        stack_device.append(self.device)
        return

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        stack_device.pop()


class Context():
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx

    def __enter__(self):
        with Device("cls_dvc"):
            stack_context.append(self.ctx)
            return

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        stack_context.pop()


with Context("myctx"):
    print(stack_device[-1])  # -> None !!!
    print(stack_context[-1]) # -> myctx
```

What would be the right way to achieve same behaviour in the second case as in first case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a Device object inside your Context class, call the Device object's `__enter__` method in the Context `__enter__` method, and call the Device object's `__exit__` method in the Context `__exit__` method. If there is an error, then you can either handle it in the Context `__exit__` method or the Device `__exit__` method, whichever is more appropriate.

```
stack_device = [None]
stack_context = [None]

class Device:
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def __enter__(self):
        stack_device.append(self.device)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        stack_device.pop()


class Context:
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.cls_dvc = Device("cls_dvc")

    def __enter__(self):
        self.cls_dvc.__enter__()
        stack_context.append(self.ctx)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        stack_context.pop()
        self.cls_dvc.__exit__(err_type, err_value, traceback)


with Context("myctx"):
    print(stack_device[-1])  # -> cls_dvc
    print(stack_context[-1]) # -> myctx
```

Comment: I thought `__enter__` would be a private member, but testing showed it is public.

Comment: @DanielChin Python doesn't really have private members. Even if you use two leading underscores in an attribute name, you can [still access it from other objects](https://towardsdatascience.com/private-protected-attributes-in-python-demystified-once-and-for-all-9456d4e56414) if you know the naming system.

Comment: Also, `__enter__` is a magic method, so Python treats it specially. Name mangling (see above linked article) doesn't apply like it would to an attribute like `__foo`. See the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for a list of all magic methods and attributes.

Answer (score 4):

The key to the failure of your code is that a *with* statement calls ***enter*** when its block, and ***exit*** when the block ends. Having a ***with Device*** block inside the ***enter*** of Context means that the *return* statement, even though inside the block, leaves it, thus triggering the ***exit*** of Device. You can see this course of action by adding prints inside of each special method.

There are several possible solutions to make it work:

1. If the context managers are independent, like in Robert Kearns' solution, instead of creating a super-context to create both your contexts you can use the standard Python chaining to create them in order, from left to right:

   ```
   with Context("myctx"), Device("cls_dvc"):
   ```
2. If you need access to Device attributes inside Context class (the only reason to chain them the way you do), then again you have two solutions:

   - Redesign your class structure so that a single *__enter__* initiates both contexts and a single *__exit__* cleans both contexts. In your design, only Context needs to be implemented as context manager, Device can be a regular class.
   - If you need to keep Device as an independent context manager (e.g., to use it by itself somewhere else), then Jack Taylor's solution is what you need. Note that there are several cases in Python (for example, open("filename")) that can be used as both "regular" and as "context managers". In this case, all the logic is in regular methods, while *__enter__* and *__exit__* only contain calls to the regular methods, so you don't have to call the special methods directly, as in the provided answers

Answer (score 1):

I get the right output by putting the `with Device()` manager inside the `with Context()`.

```py
stack_device = [None]
stack_context = [None]

class Device():
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def __enter__(self):
        stack_device.append(self.device)
        return

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        stack_device.pop()


class SubContext():
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = ctx

    def __enter__(self):
        stack_context.append(self.ctx)
        return


    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        stack_context.pop()

class Context:

    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.ctx = SubContext(ctx)
        self.device = Device('dev')

    def __enter__(self):
        self.ctx.__enter__()
        self.device.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.ctx.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
        self.device.__exit__(type, value, traceback)

with Context("myctx"):
    print(stack_device[-1])
    print(stack_context[-1])
```

Comment: Sure. But your code is not the same in sense that you are using 2 `with` statements while snippet 1 manages to get same output with just 1. If I am writing a library and want my client to use just my `Context` object. It would not be great if I have to ask them to also wrap it with 3rd party `Device` object at the same time, right?

Comment: I added another solution. Im just spit balling, is that something that would work for you?